# How to stop false matchTemplate matches in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I was wondering if someone with OpenCV experience can help me out with a small program im making. Essentially it trys to find a picture and when it does it will move the mouse and click on it. I wrote what I have in cpp using matchTemplate but my issue is that im getting a lot of false matches around the screen (any darkish pixels it seems because the template is pretty dark) and I assume that is due to the colors of the image, it can match a lot of different things? I am not sure what to do as I just started looking at OpenCV. It was very hard to find easy to understand resources for C++ OpenCV.

I've tried converting the files to different types (gray scale etc). The desktop image gets a colored 8UC4 so I also tried converting the template to BGRA for that. I read about thresholding/threshold but found it very confusing and couldn't find much other than than the one openCV doc about the function. I'm super new to OpenCV this and would appreciate some help in how to process the image better.

```
void find_accept(string acceptTemplate, int matchMethod)
{
    // init mat of imgs
    Mat src_img;
    Mat template_img;
    Mat result_mat;
    Mat debug_img;

    // method: TM_SQDIFF, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, TM _CCORR, TM_CCORR_NORMED, TM_CCOEFF, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
    int match_method = matchMethod;

    // getting the desktop window
    HWND hwndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();

    // checking source image read in
    template_img = imread(acceptTemplate, IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (template_img.data == NULL) 
    {
        cout << "template read in failed...\n";
        return;
    }
    cvtColor(template_img, template_img, COLOR_BGR2BGRA);

    int key = 0;
    while(key != 27)
    {
        src_img = hwnd2mat(hwndDesktop);
        debug_img = src_img.clone();
        //cout << "src: " << type2str(src_img.type()) << endl;
        //cout << "tmpl: " << type2str(template_img.type()) << endl;
        matchTemplate(src_img, template_img, result_mat, match_method);
        normalize(result_mat, result_mat, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());

        double minVal; double maxVal; 
        Point minLoc, maxLoc, matchLoc;
        minMaxLoc(result_mat, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
        
        if( match_method  == TM_SQDIFF || match_method == TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )  matchLoc = minLoc;
        else matchLoc = maxLoc;

        rectangle(
            debug_img,
            matchLoc,
            Point(matchLoc.x + template_img.cols, matchLoc.y + template_img.rows),
            CV_RGB(255,0,0),
            3);

        imshow("debug_img", debug_img);
        imshow("result img", result_mat);
        imshow("source image", src_img);
        key = waitKey(10);
    }
}
```

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7LRH.png)
[wider view of template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDK4u.png)

the source is a screenshot of my entire screen that I get from hwnd2mat function I found in another thread.

Comment: Currently you are only searching the best match, but you dont threshold the matching value. Have a look at min or max (depending on the used method) value for good and false matches and find a suitable threshold.

Comment: I am currently using TM_SQDIFF which would be the min match value. Would I just need to set a threshold variable and see if its above(or below?) the threshold? What is the best way to determine matching method to use and what the threshold() used for then?

Comment: Yes, just test if(min > threshold): it's-a-false-detection; I think finding a working threshold is best done empirically, by looking at as many true and false detections as possible.

Comment: Ive been trying playing around with threshold values (I think) by seeing what the minVal is when I used TM_SQDIFF and I also played around with other matching methods (I tried TM_CCORR_NORMED which uses maxVal). For some reason when I console out the maxVal its always one no matter the method.  I do something like this-> cout << "match val: " << minVal << endl; double threshold = -0.0000001; if(minVal < threshold) Unfortunately I am having a hard time understanding and getting a good value as I keep getting bad matches and I need it to match exactly when the template is found and no other time

Comment: Remove the normalize(result_mat...) call, that is destroying your template matching result.

Comment: Micka! Thank you so much I got it working and the values were more stable to find a suitable threshold. I am wondering what normalize is even for as I found part of my code from this https://gist.github.com/yoggy/1451097 I am new to OpenCV but it is very fun. I am wondering if you could explain my previous questions and this one just out of curiosity. Thank you again!